# What is the difference between ^tablespace_name and :tablespace_name in Oracle sql code?

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle, plsql, plpgsql

what is the difference between these 2?

```sql
alter table CDMM_CUST add constraint CDMM_CUSTM_EXTEN_UK unique (CUST_ID) using index TABLESPACE ^TS_INX;

alter table CDMM_CUST add constraint CDMM_CUSTM_EXTEN_UK unique (CUST_ID) using index TABLESPACE :TS_INX;
```

This is required to review these 2 statements?

```sql
alter table CDMM_CUST add constraint CDMM_CUSTM_EXTEN_UK unique (CUST_ID) using index TABLESPACE ^TS_INX;

alter table CDMM_CUST add constraint CDMM_CUSTM_EXTEN_UK unique (CUST_ID) using index TABLESPACE :TS_INX;
```

But what is the difference between ^TS_INX  and :TS_INX?

Comment: Neither are valid. The `^` is entirely unrecognized, and the attempt at using a bind variable with `:` won't work with a DDL statement. That being said, if you are finding this code embedded in some client programming environment that may do its own preprocessing, you'd have to investigate how that engine would handle these conventions (assuming they are not simply incorrect). But Oracle wouldn't know what to do with them.

Comment: You flagged `plsql`, if this is embedded in PL/SQL can you share the larger code context?

Comment: It's executed on PostgreSQL and also on Oracle later.

Comment: I see ^ and : in other places also, example:

Comment: create index IDX_FK_CUSTEXT_ID on CDM_CUST_EXTEN (CUST_ID) TABLESPACE ^TS_INDEX;

alter table CDM_CUST_EXTEN add constraint FK_CUSTEXT_CUST_ID foreign key(CUST_ID)  references CDM_CUSTOMER (ID);
alter table CDM_CUST_EXTEN add constraint CDM_CUSTOMER_EXTE_CUSTOMER_UK unique (CUST_ID) using index TABLESPACE ^TS_INDEX;

Comment: create index IDX_FK_CUSTEXT_ID on CDM_CUST_EXTEN (CUST_ID) TABLESPACE :TS_INDEX;
alter table CDM_CUST_EXTEN add constraint FK_CUSTEXT_CUST_ID foreign key(CUST_ID)  references CDM_CUSTOMER (ID);
alter table CDM_CUST_EXTEN add constraint CDM_CUSTOMER_EXTE_CUSTOMER_UK unique () using index TABLESPACE :TS_INDEX;

Comment: BEGIN
    -- we need to drop index first, otherwise it will be used
    -- to protect the constraint
    if index_exists('CDM_CUST_EXTEN', 'IDX_FK_CUSTEXT_ID') then
        execute immediate 'drop index IDX_FK_CUSTEXT_ID';
    end if;

    if not (constraint_exists('CDM_CUST_EXTEN','CDM_CUSTOMER_EXTE_CUSTOMER_UK')) then
        execute immediate 'alter table CDM_CUST_EXTEN add constraint CDM_CUSTOMER_EXTE_CUSTOMER_UK unique (CUST_ID) using index TABLESPACE ${TS_INDEX}';
   end if;

END;

Comment: DO $$   
 begin
        
        if not exists(select constraint_name
                      from information_schema.constraint_column_usage
                      where table_schema = current_schema()
                        and constraint_schema = current_schema()
                        and upper(table_name) = 'CDM_CUST_EXTEN'
                        and upper(constraint_name) = 'CDM_CUSTOMER_EXTE_CUSTOMER_UK') then
alter table CDM_CUST_EXTEN add constraint CDM_CUSTOMER_EXTE_CUSTOMER_UK unique (CUST_ID) using index TABLESPACE ${TS_DATA};
        end if;

Comment: -- drop existing non unique constraint
        if exists(select indexname
                      from pg_indexes
                      where schemaname = current_schema()
                        and upper(tablename) =  'CDM_CUST_EXTEN'
                        and upper(indexname) = 'IDX_FK_CUSTEXT_ID') then
            drop index IDX_FK_CUSTEXT_ID;
        end if;
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Comment: Then this is a question for PostgreSQL, not for Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Neither are valid SQL statements.

If you run them they will both give the output:

```
ORA-02216: tablespace name expected
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2tlzyVRI)

---

The [Database Object Names and Qualifiers documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-3C59E44A-5140-4BCA-B9E1-3039C8050C49) states:

> 6. Nonquoted identifiers must begin with an alphabetic character from your database character set. Quoted identifiers can begin with any character.
> 7. Nonquoted identifiers can only contain alphanumeric characters from your database character set and the underscore (_), dollar sign ($), and pound sign (#). Database links can also contain periods (.) and "at" signs (@). Oracle strongly discourages you from using $ and # in nonquoted identifiers.
>
>    Quoted identifiers can contain any characters and punctuations marks as well as spaces. However, neither quoted nor nonquoted identifiers can contain double quotation marks or the null character (\0).

- `^TS_INX` is invalid syntax as it is an unquoted identifier and does not start with an alphabetic character.
- `:TS_INX` is also invalid syntax as it is an unquoted identifier and does not start with an alphabetic character.

  `:` is also used to prefix bind variables; however, it is not valid to specify a bind variable in a DDL statement so it would still be invalid.

---

> This is required to review these 2 statements?

Your system could be using a pre-processor to parse and modify the code before sending it to the database; if so then it is possible that one-or-both statements are valid syntax for your pre-processor and that the pre-processor will transform them into valid SQL statements before sending them to the database.

But, solely considering evaluating them as SQL statements in the context of an Oracle database, both statements are invalid syntax.